# Alternative to CGenFF for generating large ligand topology

Tags: molecular-dynamics, gromacs, proteins, forcefields, charmm

I am now preparing a ligand topology following [GROMACS protein-ligand tutorial](http://www.mdtutorials.com/gmx/complex/02_topology.html).
However, I have a large ligand (446 atoms).

```
$ wc -l my_ligand.pdb
446 my_ligand.pdb
```

When I tried to upload `my_ligand_fix.mol2` to [CGenFF server](https://cgenff.umaryland.edu), I noticed it the maximum number of atoms allowable is 384.

[image]

Note that `my_ligand_fix.mol2` has gone through processing right up to `sort_mol2_bonds.pl` output.

Is there a way to get around this?
Or what other alternative to CGenFF that I can use instead?

-Sca

Answer (score 7):

I'd use OpenMM's `openmmforcefields` package, which is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/openmm/openmmforcefields).

I haven't used it extensively, but I recommended to a student in a colleague's lab and they've found it useful.

Small molecule force fields:

- GAFF 1.x and 2.x parameters
- OpenFF parameters

Biomolecule force fields:

- Amber-type (albeit not `Amber ff19SB` yet)
- CHARMM-type

And it will, if needed, generate AM1-BCC partial charges using OpenEye or `antechamber` tools.

The README gives some example Python code:

```
# Create an OpenFF Molecule object for benzene from SMILES
from openff.toolkit.topology import Molecule
molecule = Molecule.from_smiles('c1ccccc1')
# Create the GAFF template generator
from openmmforcefields.generators import GAFFTemplateGenerator
gaff = GAFFTemplateGenerator(molecules=molecule)
# Create an OpenMM ForceField object with AMBER ff14SB and TIP3P with compatible ions
from simtk.openmm.app import ForceField
forcefield = ForceField('amber/protein.ff14SB.xml', 'amber/tip3p_standard.xml', 'amber/tip3p_HFE_multivalent.xml')
# Register the GAFF template generator
forcefield.registerTemplateGenerator(gaff.generator)
# You can now parameterize an OpenMM Topology object that contains the specified molecule.
# forcefield will load the appropriate GAFF parameters when needed, and antechamber
# will be used to generate small molecule parameters on the fly.
from simtk.openmm.app import PDBFile
pdbfile = PDBFile('t4-lysozyme-L99A-with-benzene.pdb')
system = forcefield.createSystem(pdbfile.topology)
```

For example you could load your molecules like this from an `.sdf` file (again from the README):

```
molecules = Molecule.from_file('molecules.sdf')
gaff = GAFFTemplateGenerator(molecules=molecules, forcefield='gaff-2.11')
```

Comment: I understand this isn't a direct answer to the question, since the author asked about Gromacs and CGenFF and I'm recommending something totally different. But it works for any size ligand, so it solves the underlying problem.